# How to return the fetched data back to my view?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, yii

How to return the fetched data (in this case: `$arr`) back to my view
(which I can manipulate like displaying in a table).
If I have this in my controller action processed via ajax:

```
public function actionFetchregularload(){
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->limit = 15;
            $criteria->condition='semester = 2';
            $criteria->select = array('subjCode','subjDesc','lec','lab','units');
            $criteria->addSearchCondition('yrLvl', $_GET['yrlevel']);
            $data = CompeProspectusA::model()->findAll($criteria);
            $arr = array();
            foreach ($data as $item){
                    $arr[] = array(
                            'subjcode' => $item->subjCode,
                            'subjdesc' => $item->subjDesc,
                            'lab' => $item->lab,
                            'lec' => $item->lec,
                            'units' => $item->units,
                    );
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a view with your table or something else and use `renderPartial()` in your `actionFetchregularload()` like this:

`$this->renderPartial('_table', array('arr'=>$arr), false, true);`

In your main view you can use `CHtml::ajaxLink` with options (where "#contentdiv" is id of your table div):

```
CHtml::ajaxLink(
        "Update table",
        Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/fetchregularload'),
        array(    //ajaxOptions
            'type' => 'POST',
            'beforeSend' => "function(request) {
                $('#contentdiv').addClass('loading');   //add .loading class while loading - you can add background image
            }",
            'success' => "function(data) {
                $('#contentdiv').removeClass('loading');
                document.getElementById('contentdiv').innerHTML=data;
            }",
        ),
        //htmlOptions
        array('href' => Yii::app()->createUrl('controller/fetchregularload')); 
    );
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/36095-how-to-return-the-fetched-data-back-to-my-view/page__gopid__173629#entry173629